# Copy a list and an associated iterator

Tags: c++, list, iterator

Suppose I have a list that I iterate over.  When I find something interesting I want to take a copy and do something at that point:

```
std::list<int> a;
for(auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
{
   if(is_interesting(*i))
   {
      std::list<int> b = a;  // take a copy
      do_something(b, i);  // :(
   }
}
```

Of course this is not going to work because the iterator `i` refers to `a` and not `b`.  How do I get an iterator `j` that refers to the same position in `b` that `i` refers to in `a`?

Comment: You can do it with `std::distance` and `std::advance`, but this seems pretty fishy to me. It wouldn't be _so_ bad on a random-access container. Why do you need to copy the entire list? And why inside a loop?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I imagine that could work, but be unnecessarily slow.  I want to add a modified version of my list to my list of lists.

Comment: @wxffles Huh what do you mean "unnecessarily slow"? It's the fastest you can do until you address my queries about your current constraints.

Comment: _" I imagine that could work, but be unnecessarily slow."_ - You're making a _copy_ of a _list_ and you're talking about `distance` and `advance` being slow? Pppffttt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
std::list<int> b = a;
std::list<int>::iterator j = b.begin();
std::advance(j, std::distance(a.begin(), i));
```

You could optimize this by incrementing a counter with your loop condition, instead of recalculating the offset.  The `distance` and `advance` functions for `list` traverse the list, of course.

As noted in comments, the need to do this operation suggests there might be a better higher-level design possibility for your code. Without knowing why you need to copy the list, perhaps you only need to copy part of it, e.g.

```
std::list<int> b2( i, a.end() );
```

If you do need the whole list then here is an option (not sure if this has better complexity than the first option!):

```
std::list<int> b( a.begin(), i );
std::list<int> b2( i, a.end() );
std::list<int>::iterator j = b2.begin();
b.splice( b.end(), b2 );    // moves all of b2's elements into b
```

Splicing is O(1) for `list` of course, since it is just twiddling a couple of pointers. The splice is guaranteed to preserve iterators even if the object moved to a different list.

Comment: I think the final example is equivalent to the first in terms of semantics, complexity and — near enough — actual runtime.